# Retrieve the Median from a decimal column using PERCENTILE_CONT SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, percentile

I have a table Prices Like:

```
ID                   PurchasePriceCalc
0146301              0.002875161
00006L00             0.00396
00087G03             NULL
00001G04             0.0020004
00006S               0.003689818
01580h01             NULL
00082EE00            0.002462687
00038R05             0.002237565
01666R01             0.002666667
```

I Would like to get the Median per each PurchasePriceCalc and then subtract the result with the PurchasePriceCalc, for a better explanation the Formula should be : (PurchasePriceCalc - Median(PurchasePriceCalc)).

I'm using the query below but is not working:

```
SELECT ID,PurchasePriceCalc, PurchasePriceCalc - PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PurchasePriceCalc)
                         OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS MediaCalc   FROM Prices
```

This is how should be the Output, (Yellow Column).
[image]

Any assistance or help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Yes is unique and is retrieving 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is with `OVER (PARTITION BY ID)`. If ID is UNIQUE then each group consists of only one row that is why you get all values equal 0/NULL.

You should remove `PARTITION BY` part.

```
SELECT ID,PurchasePriceCalc, 
 PurchasePriceCalc - PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5)
                   WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY PurchasePriceCalc) OVER () AS MediaCalc 
FROM Prices;
```

Comment: Still retrieving 0

Comment: Maybe im just being dense, but if each ID is unique and the dataset has only one row per ID, then you will always only have one price value per ID, and the median of that single value is just the value, no?

Comment: @JCACERES How do you store values (REAL/FLOAT/DECIMAL)? All your data points are close to 0 so it could be rounding error.

Comment: Seem to be working fine here http://rextester.com/ODXBC93145 . check `PurchasePriceCalc` should be float

Comment: I'm selecting the values from a WITH statement because is a calculated field.

Comment: add `* 1.0` to the calculated field to make sure is float

Comment: @JCACERES Please post screenshot of your **actual query, data and resultset**. Do you copy result from SSMS to Excel?

Comment: Yes I did, SSMS to Excel, same data.

Comment: @JCACERES So check it with SSMS only. You may lost metadata info [Copy Results Grid data to Excel](http://www.ssmsboost.com/Features/ssms-add-in-results-grid-data-to-excel)

Comment: I have tried with *1.0 but is retrieving wrong amount.

Comment: Well we cant guess unless you show us some code. As you can see in the provide it rextexter the Lukaz code work as expected.

Comment: It seems to be working but it isn't because any of the result are the same.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza what code do you need? I'm working with the above, but still not working.

Comment: this code works. http://rextester.com/ODXBC93145 you can use rextester to load your code so we can see why fails

Comment: Sorry I just realize "Isnt working" mean does not provide the correct result. Let me check again

Comment: Ok, it seems to be that the code is trying to take the Median per each PriceCalc instead of give just 1 value. and then subtract that value with the PriceCalc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178086/discussion-between-juan-carlos-oropeza-and-jcaceres).